# Kotlin function won't return false, returns nothing when expecting false

Tags: function, loops, kotlin, boolean, return

```
private fun check_letter_row(v:ViewGroup, i: Int):Boolean {

    helped_answer = helped_answer.lowercase()

    for (a in 0..helped_answer.length - 1) {
        if (v.getChildAt(i).tag.toString().lowercase() == helped_answer[a].toString()) {
            v.getChildAt(i).visibility = View.GONE
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Can't get this function to return false. It returns true or returns nothing. I want it to return false so I can check other rows when it returns false. Where am I doing wrong? I am getting "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" instead of getting false. But when it's true, there is no exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns nothing"? And the return type should be `Boolean` instead of `Bool`, there is no such type in Kotlin's stdlib

Comment: Still doesn't work. Will return true, but it won't return false. If the check is false it returns nothing. the function also stops the following codes being executed.

Comment: > "If the check is false it returns nothing" – what exactly does it mean? does it throw an exception?

Comment: I don't know how to check for exceptions in Android Studio. But this function is preventing other codes from executing if it doesn't return true. It just won't return false.

Comment: You can use *Logcat* in Android Studio, fatals are also logged there

Comment: Only error I get is "A resource failed to call close." I don't get anything if I make the function work.

Comment: Have You tried with "If... Else" ?

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens when you try to index an array with an index less than 0 or more than its {size minus 1}. In your case, the loop correctly goes through all valid indices of `helped_answer`, so that's not the source of the problem. The only remaining possibility is an exception being thrown by `ViewGroup.getChildAt` because you're passing it an invalid index value.

Note that the index you're passing to `getChildAt` doesn't vary inside the loop; so, for clarity and readability, it would help to take it outside of the loop.

Consider what should be done if an invalid index is passed to your `check_letter_row` function. Should it throw an exception, return true or return false? This is something only you can decide, depending on how you want to use this function.

Try the following, which is functionally equivalent to your original code:

```
private fun check_letter_row(v:ViewGroup, i: Int): Boolean {

    if (i !in 0..v.getChildCount() - 1) {
        // TODO: decide what to do here. Example:
        return false // or throw IllegalArgumentException
    }

    val childView = v.getChildAt(i)
    val childViewTag = childView.tag.toString().lowercase()
    helped_answer = helped_answer.lowercase()

    if (childViewTag.length == 1 && childViewTag in helped_answer) {
        childView.visibility = View.GONE
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```